# How to get rid of vertical space above title from slide 2

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Using this minimal example I get a vertical space above the title bar
on slide 2. This seems to be an unfortunate interaction with CVS
versions of pgf/TikZ (I am using the build from 28 September 2010, the
version on CTAN does not have this problem)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{split}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Foo}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Bar}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy fix?

My list of files is:

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2010/06/21 development version 3.10 A class for
typesetting pre
sentations (rcs-revision a6b1a8434d30)
beamerbasercs.sty    2010/06/12 (rcs-revision c3821710bb40)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2010/04/27 (rcs-revision 982469101dd6)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2008/12/21 v4.2 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its
modes (HO)
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.00-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2009/08/25 v0.04m Graphics/color for pdfTeX
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.00-cvs (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfrcs.sty    2008/05/19 v2.00-cvs (rcs-revision 1.22)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
hyperref.sty    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
 hycolor.sty    2009/10/02 v1.5 Code for color options of hyperref/
bookmark (HO
)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/10/02 xcolor patch
  pd1enc.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition
(HO)
etexcmds.sty    2007/12/12 v1.2 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty    2009/08/13 v3.4 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2009/07/30 v1.5 Key value parser with default handler
support
(HO)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations
(HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2009/09/23 v0.6 LuaTeX support for pdfTeX utility
functions (
HO)
ifluatex.sty    2009/04/17 v1.2 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2009/08/05 v1.0 Some LaTeX kernel commands for general
use (HO)

atbegshi.sty    2008/07/31 v1.9 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2010/07/12  (rcs-revision 6648c3177e4e)
beamerbasefont.sty    2010/05/10  (rcs-revision cd36e8a33c6b)
 amssymb.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision bff0a9294b45)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2010/05/07  (rcs-revision 5584dad462a9)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/06/12  (rcs-revision 717e481ca47a)
beamerbasesection.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision e0d9401bb743)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision bff0a9294b45)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2010/06/27  (rcs-revision 6baa2d92e6f1)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2010/07/12  (rcs-revision
09e82992d9b1)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 242ecaa6783b)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2010/06/01  (rcs-revision
81f9e33f7cc2)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerthemesplit.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemesplit.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemestructurebold.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision
d02a7cf4d8ae)
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2007/05/29 v2.31 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
compendium.out
compendium.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
 ***********
```

Comment: The problem is apparently reported in this bug report <http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3023390&group_id=142562&atid=752792> and this one <http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/67/vertical-offset-of-slide-content-for-pages-1-with-current>.

Comment: typo in tilte..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [link provided by Martin](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/67) this issue has been resolved in the new PGF 2.10.

Comment: Yes, this problem has been fixed.